# EXCHANGE-WS Not able to get folder

Tags: exchangewebservices

I am using exchange-ws implemented by [Independentsoft](http://www.independentsoft.com/) to access 0356 web service. I am trying to read/move emails from shared email box. I am able to read email successfully but when i am trying to move the red email to user created folder getting an error folder not found. when i use serice.findFoler with the restriction(folder display name), method doesn't return anything. Also i tried to list all folder but folders created by me not listing. Only standard folder like Inbox, Draft, Sent Item listing. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you either have a problem with your code (which you need to show) or permissions (eg you may have only been delegated access to certain folder in the Mailbox). In that case try to add full rights to the Mailbox using Add-MailboxPermission

Comment: Sounds like you need to show us some code if you want help.